# System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. entity framework issue

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .net standard 2 class library that I want to connect to a sql server db using entity framework.

I am getting the following error

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.ProviderCodeGenerator.GenerateUseProvider(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.GenerateOnConfiguring(String connectionString, Boolean suppressConnectionStringWarning)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.GenerateClass(IModel model, String contextName, String connectionString, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean suppressConnectionStringWarning)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.WriteCode(IModel model, String namespace, String contextName, String connectionString, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean suppressConnectionStringWarning)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpModelGenerator.GenerateModel(IModel model, String namespace, String contextDir, String contextName, String connectionString, ModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String namespace, String language, String contextDir, String contextName, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

When I run the command

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testdb;user id=dbuser;password=test" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I am beginning to really hate .net Core. Being forced to use CLI is bad enough but it is now getting ridiculous with vague errors like this.

Comment: Can you show the full error message?

Comment: Edited question to show full error

Comment: Wheres the code that you’re calling that gives this error?

Comment: It is the scaffolding command I noted in the question.